# Is there a Rust idiom for converting types of closure arguments?

Tags: rust

I want to write code that's as readable as possible, but one pattern keeps frustrating me.

Let's say I have a closure such as:

```rust
let vec: Vec<u32> = ...;
let total: i32 = vec.iter().enumerate().map(|(x, y)| x - y).sum();
```

Then the types of x & y are `usize` and `&u32` respectively, and I get the error:

```
20 |     let total: i32 = vec.iter().enumerate().map(|(x, y)| x - y).sum();
   |                                                              ^ expected `usize`, found `u32`
```

Which I can obviously work around with `map(|(x, y)| x as i32 - *y as i32)`, but that uglifies the actual business logic (imagine if the expression used both variables several times).

Assuming it's guaranteed that overflow etc. won't happen, I'd like to find the most concise way to unclutter the body of the closure from inline `as xxx` expressions.

Without pulling this out into a function, is there are better way to express the desire to convert input types?

I was hoping that `map(|(x as i32, *y as i32)| x - y)` or some-such might work, but it doesn't seem promising.

Obviously another approach would be:

```rust
    let total: i32 = vec.iter().enumerate()
        .map(|(x, y)| (x as i32, *y as i32))
        .map(|(x, y)| x - y).sum();
```

But that also feels unsatisfying. So am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. If the reference was the only problem, you could dereference it within the closure's header by using `&`, but this isn't possible for conversions. A macro can do that, but it's not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in this case, since it is `enumerate()` that gives the `usize`, you can replace it with `zip(0..)`:

```rust
let total: i32 = vec.iter().zip(0..).map(|(x, y)| x - y).sum::<u32>() as i32;
```

I'm not sure this is better, but it also works.

Beware, however, that `zip(0..)` versus `enumerate()` is not exactly the same, since `zip(0..)`  cannot implement [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) or [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html). It might even have performance disadvantages, although this is less likely because it can give a correct `size_hint()`.

Comment: Yes, I mean my question was a arbitrary example really, so not always `enumerate()`, but thanks for the pointer.